# Function to find the index of the beginning and end of the longest run in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to write code that finds the longest run in a list of Boolean values and return the index of the first and last value of that run.  For example, if L is [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False]. then the function would return (3, 6), since the longest run of False is from 3 to 6. This is what I have so far but it doesn't work properly.

```
def longestFalse(L):
endindex = 0
maxcount=0
counter=0
for i in range(len(L)):
    if L[i] == False:
        counter += 1
    elif L[i] == True:
        if counter>maxcount:
            maxcount = counter
            endindex = i
            counter = 0
    elif i == len(L) - 1 :
        if L[i-1] == L[i]:
            counter += 1
            maxcount = count
            endindex = i
return endindex-maxcount,endindex-1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of the starting index and the length of the longest run so far, as well as the starting index of the current run, and if the current index minus the starting index of the current run is greater than the length of the longest run so far, make the current starting index and the said length the new starting index and the length of the longest run:

```
def longest_false(L):
    start = max_start = None
    max_size = -1
    for i, v in enumerate(L):
        if v:
            start = None
        else:
            if start is None:
                start = i
            if i - start > max_size:
                max_start = start
                max_size = i - start
    if max_start is None:
        return None, None # in case there is no False at all in the given list
    return max_start, max_start + max_size
```

Comment: This fails with `[True, False]`.

Comment: Oops indeed. Fixed then.

Answer (score 1):

Use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

values = [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False]

start = 0
runs = []
for key, run in groupby(values):
    length = sum(1 for _ in run)
    runs.append((start, start + length - 1))
    start += length

result = max(runs, key=lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
(3, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more faster iterative version with `itertools.groupby` feature:

```
from itertools import groupby

def get_longest_run(lst):
    curr_len, run_span = 0, 0
    for k, gr in groupby(lst):
        len_ = len(list(gr))
        if (run_span and len_ > (run_span[1] + 1) - run_span[0]) or len_ > curr_len:
            run_span = (curr_len, curr_len + len_ - 1)
        curr_len += len_

    return run_span

lst = [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False]
print(get_longest_run(lst))   # (3, 6)
```

---

Time performance comparison (to previous answer):

```
In [144]: lst = [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False]                                   

In [145]: def get_longest_run_deniel(lst): 
     ...:     start = 0 
     ...:     runs = [] 
     ...:     for key, run in groupby(lst): 
     ...:         length = sum(1 for _ in run) 
     ...:         runs.append((start, start + length - 1)) 
     ...:         start += length 
     ...:  
     ...:     result = max(runs, key=lambda x: x[1] - x[0]) 
     ...:     return result 
     ...:                                                                                                                    

In [146]: def get_longest_run(lst): 
     ...:     curr_len, run_span = 0, 0 
     ...:     for k, gr in groupby(lst): 
     ...:         len_ = len(list(gr)) 
     ...:         if (run_span and len_ > (run_span[1] + 1) - run_span[0]) or len_ > curr_len: 
     ...:             run_span = (curr_len, curr_len + len_ - 1) 
     ...:         curr_len += len_ 
     ...:  
     ...:     return run_span 
     ...:                                                                                                                    

In [147]: %timeit get_longest_run_deniel(lst)                                                                                
6.06 µs ± 168 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [148]: %timeit get_longest_run(lst)                                                                                       
3.67 µs ± 131 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solution as a first-year CS student here that could be easy for you to understand

```
def longestFalse(L):
    count = -1 #Set count and highest count to -1 so that it will count at correct index
    highest_count = -1
    index_of_highest_count = []
    L.insert(len(L),True) #This to account for False being at the end of the list
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if L[i] == False:
            count += 1
        else: #When encounter True
            if count > highest_count: 
                highest_count = count
                index_of_highest_count.pop() if index_of_highest_count else False 
                #If statement after pop to ensure no error when list is empty
                index_of_highest_count.append(i-1) #Decrease index by 1 due to it currently at True
                count = -1 #Reset count when encounter True
            count = -1 #Reset count when there is only one run of False.
    L.pop() #Remove the last index placeholder 'True' when loop is done.
    if len(index_of_highest_count) == 0:
        return (None,None)
    return(index_of_highest_count[0]-highest_count,index_of_highest_count[0])
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.

Comment: @AzharKhan, I have just commented, thank you.